# object.method() vs object.method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im fairly new to JavaScript and I'm having difficulty in understanding this syntax.

```
document.querySelector('dice').style.display='none';
```

My understanding is we are calling the querySelector method on the document object - this returns a selection. Now we call the style method on this selection - this returns a style object. Next we change its display property to 'none' to hide it.

If this is correct, shouldn't it be `.style().display = 'none'?`

If indeed style is a method, shouldn't brackets be required when invoking it?

Comment: style is not a function.

Comment: Please remove `?` from  `.style().display = 'none'?`.

Comment: `style` is an object, not a function.

Comment: style is not a function neither is it a factory function, style is an object, with properties that enables you to manipulate the looks of any DOM object

Answer (score 1):

The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

**Note:** The querySelector() method only returns the first element that matches the specified selectors. To return all the matches, use the querySelectorAll() method instead.

If the selector matches an ID in document that is used several times (Note that an "id" should be unique within a page and should not be used more than once), it returns the first matching element.

Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) to know more about query selector.

The 'style' property is used to apply some inline style to a dom element through the script. According to the example which you have mentioned,**document.querySelector('dice').style.display='none';** that simply hide a first dom element 'dice'.

Comment: *"name"* in this context is confusing at best. Could you try to clarify it, because it will match a `<dice>` element, not a `<foo name="dice">`

Comment: Also, when you [copy paste from external resources](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp), it's required to cite your sources and good to mark it as citation (`>  The text` in answers editor)

Answer (score 0):

`style` is used in css. You shouldn't use`style()`. When you are typing`element.style.dispaly`, you are allowing the browser to know that you want to change the css property of the element.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

> While getting, it returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element...

It just happens to be accessed as a plain property that references an object, rather than a function that returns an object.

Also note

> `document.querySelector('dice')`

probably isn't valid unless `dice` is a special HTML tag. You might be looking for `.querySelector('.dice')` (class selection) or `.querySelector('$dice')` (id selection) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Style` is the `property` of the DOM Object and not the `method`.

So it is as good as using following syntax:

```
const person = {
  name: {
   first: 'ABC'
  }
}

person.name.first = 'CDE';
```

Which is similar to

`document.querySelector('dice').style.display='none';`

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` is a method. Which means it is a function which is stored as an object property. When you call the method `document.querySelector('div')` it returns the first div element in your document. The returned value will be an object which contains attributes from the object.
[Link to a jsBin that displays document.querySelector output](https://jsbin.com/lapipog/edit?html,js,console).

So `document.querySelector('div').style` will display its styles. And  you can take a particular value from it and change its style.